# How do I log exceptions with appropriate linebreaks using Monolog with Slim 3?

Tags: php, slim, monolog

```
$container['logger'] = function (\Slim\Container $c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], $settings['level']));
    return $logger;
};

$container['errorHandler'] = function (\Slim\Container $container) {
    return function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, \Exception $exception) use ($container) {
        /** @var \Monolog\Logger $monoLog */
        $monoLog = $container->logger;
        $monoLog->addError((string)$exception);

        $response->getBody()->rewind();
        return $response->withStatus(500)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            ->write("Oops, something's gone wrong!");
    };
};

$container['phpErrorHandler'] = function ($container) {
    return $container['errorHandler'];
};
```

When ever an exception occurs I get a single line in the error log. Perhaps my memory is going fuzzy but the default PHP error logging would format things nicely on multiple lines...

Is there a way to format it nicely? Or do I have manually format it using something like:

```
    $monoLog->addError($exception->getMessage());
    $monoLog->addError($exception->getTraceAsString());
    $monoLog->addError($exception->getFile());
    $monoLog->addError($exception->getCode());
    $monoLog->addError($exception->getLine());
```

Even with the above the trace appears as a single line.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Monolog Formatter setting and Slim has no say in this.

The way to do this nicely is use a Formatters in MonoLog.

The default formatter is the [LineFormatter](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php)

```
public function __construct($format = null, $dateFormat = null, $allowInlineLineBreaks = false, $ignoreEmptyContextAndExtra = false)
```

As you can see the third parameter is `$allowInlineLineBreaks` so you can set that to true.
For example:

```
$handler = new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], $settings['level']);
$lineFormatter = new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, true);
$handler->setFormatter($lineFormatter);
$logger->pushHandler($handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around using regex:

```
$traceStrings = preg_split(
            "/(#\d+)/",
            $exception->getTraceAsString(),
            null,
            PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
    );
/** @var \Monolog\Logger $monoLog */
$monoLog = $container->logger;
$monoLog->addError($exception->getMessage());
$monoLog->addError($exception->getTraceAsString());
foreach ($traceStrings as $ts)
    $monoLog->addError($ts);
$monoLog->addError($exception->getFile());
$monoLog->addError($exception->getCode());
$monoLog->addError($exception->getLine());
```